# Trying to recover files from a Windows 7 machine using Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, data-recovery, live-cd

I can't boot my Windows 7 machine and the recovery tool won't load either. I need to recover the files from my hard drive.  Every guide I come across shows you can choose the language and then select "run without making any changes to my computer".  So I downloaded the ISO file to a CD and pop it in and I try to run it, but it's not giving me any of those options or questions, it looks like it's just installing the Ubuntu OS.  I don't want to install Ubuntu.  I just need to recover my files.  How come the options aren't coming up like I've seen [here for example](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/)?

Basically I just want to make sure I run this only to recover my files, not install the software. Is it still possible to **Try Ubuntu Without Installing**?  Is there some installation that has to take place before it will give the prompts I should be seeing?

Comment: When you say recover, do you mean backup files or restore files that you have deleted?

Comment: I mean pull them off the hard drive that isn't booting up.  I didn't delete anything.  My computer won't boot up.  I never said anything about restoring deleted files.

Comment: Do you not get this option http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Ubuntu-13-04-Online-Search-Sends-the-User-s-Geographical-Location-2.jpg?1359741486 What options do you get?

Answer (score 0):

There's two menus in which you can select to run Ubuntu off the LiveCD, one during boot to the CD and one whilst you're inside the OS and the installer is visible.

I've had issues where the first menu was not displayed during the boot of the CD in which I had to press one of the <kbd>f10</kbd> - <kbd>f12</kbd> keys to bring up the language selection -> boot options menu. I did this as the cd was booting, just as I saw the Ubuntu [disc loading screen.](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/images/installingprecise00.jpg)

If this does not work for you, could you please post more information on what you DO see from the installer once you're booted.